# Rails 4: update_attributes with different role

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, update-attributes

In rails 3 we could use `update_attributes` as below

```
@customer.update_attributes(params[:customer], :as => :default) 
or
@customer.update_attributes(params[:customer], :as => :admin)
```

and our attributes accessible would be defined as

```
attr_accessible :fname, :lname, :as => [:default, :admin]
attr_accessible :status, :as => [:admin]
```

But in rails 4, update_attributes does not accept second parameter. So how can I convert the above code to work in rails 4?

I tried something like this

```
  @customer.update_attributes(customer_params)

private
  def customer_params
    params.require(:customer).permit(:fname, :lname, :status )
  end
```

But I don't know how to pass the role in rails 4 while updating attributes. I can not do something like this.

```
  @customer.update_attributes(customer_params, :as => :admin)
```

This is not allowed in rails 4. So how can I do similar thing in rails 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at strong parameters. The permitted attributes should be determined in the controller not the model

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters

For example the controller would have

```
def customer_params
   if current_user.admin?
     params.require(:customer).permit(:fname, :lname, :status)
   else
     params.require(:customer).permit(:fname, :lname)
   end
end

def update
  @customer.update_attributes(customer_params)
  ...
end
```